# Error connecting to remote MySQL server [ERROR 1042 (HY000): Can't get hostname for your address]

Tags: mysql, windows-xp, hosts-file

I have MySQL 5.5 Server setup on a Windows machine.

I am able to connect to the server from console / app running on the same machine but not from a remote machine. While connecting using the following command:

```
mysql -h xx.xx.xx.xx --port=3306 -u root -p
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR 1042 (HY000): Can't get hostname for your address

I have tried putting the entry of client IP in server's `%windir%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` file as:

```
<client-ip>  <client-hostname>
```

- Server: MySQL 5.5
- OS: Windows XP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is to do with the fact that MySQL tries to establish the DNS name associated with your IP address on connect. [See here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/dns.html) for more information at the MySQL site.

You have two options:

1) Fix the connecting machine's reverse DNS. Since you've already added the machine to the hosts file, this might be unnecessary. You should also issue a FLUSH HOSTS statement on the MySQL server. See the same link above for more information about this.

2) Run MySQL with the '--skip-name-resolve' option. However, if you do this, you won't be able to use DNS names in GRANT statements. Instead you'll be restricted to using IP addresses.

2.1) or put in *my.ini* :

```
[mysqld]
skip-name-resolve
```

I'd recommend (1) if you can.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 The 2nd option worked..

Comment: @Link down..............

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a [reported bug in MySQL ver5.5](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=50417). It was resolved using the following option in [server] section of `my.ini` file

```
skip-name-resolve
```

It disables the [DNS lookup by MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/dns.html) for connecting peers.

The only thing to keep in mind is:

> ...in this case, you can use only IP
>   numbers in the MySQL grant tables.

Comment: Link down............

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue but on Windows 7. Disabling the Windows Firewall worked for me.